# Android: Downloading an NTLM-authentication-protected file

Tags: java, android, sharepoint, authentication, ntlm

I want to download a file from a **Sharepoint** server that protected with **NTLM** authentication from my **Android** application. I found some tutorials and couldn't successful.

I tried using [The Java CIFS Client Library](http://jcifs.samba.org/) and did not successful again.

I investigated this post: [Manipulating SharePoint list items with Android (JAVA) and NTLM Authentication](http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/manipulating-sharepoint-list-items-with-android-java-and-ntlm-authentication/) but i do not want to consume a webservice, i just want to download a file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you plan to communicate with SharePoint without using a Web Service? If not you will have to set up some sort of web page where you can get a byte array back by sending the required information like username, password and filename by querystring - would that do?

Comment: I have a url to a file like this: http://sub.domain.com//FolderName/FileName.docx and i want to download and display file to user. When i tested it in a browser, it asked me a username and password and then downloaded file.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, I succeeded to connect to Sharepoint and to get file stream, but how did you display the file to the user?

Comment: @OguzOzkeroglu : Have you got the solution for it? I am able to get data from NTLM authenticated web services using KSOAP2. I struggling to download file from a NTLM authenticated url same like you.

Comment: @MonishKamble : I was, but I don't remember right now, sorry.

Comment: @OguzOzkeroglu : Thank you for the reply. Its ok. I did it.

Comment: @OguzOzkeroglu bununla ilgili çözüm nedir acaba?

Comment: @arenko 9+ yıl olmuş maalesef pek bir detay hatırlamıyorum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use standard Java `java.net.Authenticator` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html? If it doesn't support NTLM check http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/auth/NTCredentials.html and related `org.apache.http` package. Also look at blog http://mrrask.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/android-authenticating-via-ntlm/ where it is shown how to use it. In par

Answer (score 3):

Why complicate things

You should be able to send the authentication in the Uri.

```
URL url = new URL ("http://user:pass@sub.domain.com/FolderName/FileName.docx");
```

This technique should work with both Windows Authentication and Basic Authentication

Comment: Use an account that works. Tested this on 5(!) different SharePoint servers here and it works everywhere.

Comment: The server may be configured to accept only certain authentication protocols.  In the cases that work, perhaps the admin set it to work with ANY auth (including basic http auth, not just NTLM).

Comment: how can i validate that the user and pass are correct?, how can i open the file or webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Chilkat, although it's not free. but you can easily implement it in your code.

[Chilkat Link](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/)